# BytesToStringRaw Delphi ''Undeclared identifier"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need help as soon as possible.
I got this problem "[ERROR]BytesToStringRaw Delphi ''Undeclared identifier"".

I heard that I can solve this using `uses` of Indy; but what "uses" I'll put?
I'm using delphi 7.

Comment: Please provide examples of your code so others can help you fix issues.

Comment: Improved some grammar and some formatting, for better readability.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, is my first time here.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for poor grammar, I found an part of this problem. BytesToString is a function of IdHeaderCoder2022JP.pas and i don't have this unit.Thanks for the answers.

Comment: class function TIdHeaderCoderPlain.Decode(const ACharSet: string; const AData: TIdBytes): String;
begin
  Result := BytesToStringRaw(AData);
end;

is in the unit IdHeaderCoderPlain.pas